# ReferenceError: Expo is not defined-React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, expo

i'm new to react-native. I tried to use EXPO in my code. but it is saying as ReferenceError: Expo is not defined-React-Native

```
 class Main extends Component {
  
  render() {
 
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
     
     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Bas van der Linden says you need to import Constants.

```
import { Constants } from 'expo';
```

But also you need to import Platform from react-native

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 2):

Install expo constants like this `expo install expo-constants`.

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Constants.statusBarHeight,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Source: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/